# Replace some text in a string and pass it to a view in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui

I wish to convert some user input LaTeX string into HTML string. Since the replacement is some what complicated, like replacing `\textbf{...}` to `<strong>...</strong>` and `\textit{...}` to `<em>...</em>`, the `replacingOccurrences` method seems to be not enough for this purpose. Also, since the code for replacement is not directly related to UI drawing, I don't know where should one put this code.

Below is the code, I stored the text that needed to process as the initial value of `inputText`.

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct LaTeXtoHTML: View {
    @State private var inputText: String =
        """
        \\textbf{some{-}text}
        \\textit{other\{-\}text}
        ${a}$ \[{b}\]
        """
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            TextEditor(text: $inputText)
            Text(inputText)
            Spacer()
        }
    }
}

struct LaTeXtoHTML_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        LaTeXtoHTML()
    }
}
```

The desired output is

```html
<strong>some-text</strong>
<em>other{-}text</em>
${a}$ \[{b}\]
```

Basically, the rules are

(1) `\textbf{...}` converts to `<strong>...</strong>`, `\textit{...}` to `<em>...</em>`;

(2) `{` and `}` are gone, but `\{` and `\}` is preserved and shown respectively as `{`, `}`;

(3) Everything inside `$...$` or `\[...\]` is left untouched.

You don't have to achieve all these for me, some hint would suffice. Thanks in advance for any kind of help!

Comment: `NSRegularExpression` should help.

Comment: Look into Regex (Regular Expressions) and you could put this logic into a ViewModel